# 'operator' : function as left operand

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Actor
{
private:
    int health;
    int atkPower;

public:
    Actor()
    {
        health = 100;
        atkPower = 10;
    }

    int getHealth()
    {
        return health;
    }

    void setHealth(int val)
    {
        health = val;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Actor player;
    Actor enemy;

    while (enemy.getHealth <<= 0)
    {

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The while loop is the error. How can I use the return value of the function for that loop without getting an error? Also is it possible if someone could explain to me why exactly this code isn't acceptable to the compiler? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you're asking a question about a compile error, you should really paste that error. In this case it's easy to see the problem, but it's rude to ask everyone to guess something the compiler already told you for free.

Comment: You should review how to call functions in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn `enemy.getHealth <<= 0` into `enemy.getHealth() <= 0`.

`<<=` is an obscure C++ operator which is probably not what you are looking for.  It is used as `a <<= b` where `a = a << b`.  I think you mean "a less than or equal to b" which is `a <= b`.

Also `Actor::getHealth` is a function, so you need to call it as a function with no parameters with `enemy.getHealth()`

Comment: `<<=`  is a C++ operator :)

Comment: Aplogies, you're right.  It means, "bitshift myself".    `x <<= y`  is equivalent to `x = x << y`.  Certainly not what OP was trying to do.